# Grouping in django query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-3.6

I have an query set object with has two attributes: words, number_of_letters. I would like to group the words by the no of letters in them. For example, all the words with 4 letters should be grouped together. How do I do this when I don't know the maximum number of letters the grouping has? Will I be able to put the grouping into separate objects?

Also, is there a way to modify all the words in the object in one go? For example, if I need to prefix a string to all the words in the object?

Comment: Could you share your models.py?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you can just post your models.py. From your question, it is not clear, exactly what type of fields words and number_of_letters are and what they are for